# obtaining a frame with no close button and only a close button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How can i obtain a frame that doesn't have a close, minimize and restore button by default ?

And how can i obtain a frame that only has a close button as in  :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myTopLevelContainer#setUndecorated(true);
```

but only `JFrame` have got three buttons --> close, minimize and restore buttons, `JDialog` has only one close button, and `JWindow` is un-decorated by default, maybe there is your way, notice `JWindow` required `JFrame` as parent, `JFrame` should't be dispayed,

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove the button from a `JFrame`. You should have to use a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead.